# Smart pointer without reference counter

Tags: smart-pointers, reference-counting

I had a lesson in programing today and my professor mentioned smart pointers.
He said that not every smart pointer needs a reference counter, I am a bit confused...
In my understanding  the use of smart pointers is to delete an allocated memory after all the pointers and references to it is out of scope.
Did I misunderstand?
What is the use of a smart pointer without a reference counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is an example of smart-pointer without a reference counter.

It retains the sole ownership of an object and destroys the object once the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.